# Evaluating $\arccos\left(\cos \left(-\frac{7\pi}{10}\right)\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

I have the problem
$$\arccos\left(\cos \left(-\frac{7\pi}{10}\right)\right)$$
But I am confused on it.

What I did: find reference angle, which is $\frac{3\pi}{10}$, and locate its quadrant, which is the first quadrant.

I am confused on what to do from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arccos function arbitrarily restricts its **range** to $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$.  This restriction allows the arccos function to be well defined.

For example, if the arccos function allowed its range to include $-\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq 0$, then arccos$(1/\sqrt{2})$ would be ambiguously referring to either $\theta = (\pi/4)$ or $\theta = -(\pi/4)$.

So, since you are attempting to evaluate arccos$(\cos[-7\pi/10])$, the first thing to do is evaluate
$A = \cos(-7\pi/10)$.

Noting that $-7\pi/10$ is in the 3rd quadrant, you have that $A < 0$.  Therefore, the arccos$(A)$ must return a value in the 2nd quadrant.

Since, in general, $\cos(x) = \cos(-x),$ and since $(7\pi/10)$ is in the 2nd quadrant, the expression $~$ arccos$(\cos[-7\pi/10])~$ evaluates to $(7\pi/10)$.

Comment: wait so cos(x)=cos(-x), so it would be arccos(cos[7pi/10]), and since 7pi/10 is already in the range of arccos, we can "cancel" the arccos with the cos 7pi/10?

Comment: @kidwhowantstolearnpython Yes, that is a somewhat sophisticated shortcut that is valid for this particular problem.  My answer was somewhat more long-winded, but the analysis is equivalent to your comment.

Comment: ok thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

$\cos(\theta)$ is - in Quadrants 2 and 3. $\frac{-7\pi}{10}$ will yield a negative value as the angle is in Quadrant 3. Therefore its co-arc is $-\cos\frac{3\pi}{10}$. Use this hint to find your reference angle. $$-\cos\frac{3\pi}{10} = \cos\frac{-7\pi}{10}$$.

Comment: wait would it be 7pi/10 without the negative sign?

Comment: @SnipingPoodle Are you sure $-\frac{7\pi}{10}$ is in the fourth quadrant?

Comment: yeah i didnt think that either, i thought it was in the 1st quadrant

Comment: Woops sry about that, its in Quadrant 3 indeed